# how to submit the form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, html

this is my html code when i click on submit button it displays alert and then when i open the retrieveform.php it does not show me the value please solve this mystery

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'retrieveform.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('helllo');
        }
      });

    });

  });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input type="text"name="t1">
 <input type="submit"name="s1"value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and my retrieveform.php is

```
 <?php
 if($_POST['t1'])
 {
 echo $_POST['t1'];
 }
 else
 {
 echo "hekllojjio";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the element "t1" is present since it's part of your form, but empty or just empty characters .. perhaps check if this is the case?

```
<?php
    if($_POST['t1'] && !empty($_POST['t1'])) {
        echo "You submitted t1 of: ".$_POST['t1'];
    } else {
        echo "t1 is empty";
    }
?>
```

Also of note is you may want to use something like firebug to view the ajax page loaded and its results. The echo statement on the ajax loaded page will not display on the parent page unless you set the contents of the response into the page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    tValue = $(this).find(input[type=text]:first).val();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'retrieveform.php',
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('helllo');
                            $('#placeholder').html(response);
                            $('#placeholder2').html(tValue);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?PHP for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
        <form class="form" name="form_<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="form_<?PHP echo $i;?>">
            <input type="text" id="t<?PHP echo $i; ?>" name="t<?PHP echo $i; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="s<?PHP echo $i; ?>" value="submit">
        </form>
        <?PHP } ?>
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
        <div id="placeholder2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

with this your ajax loaded page's echo will be put on the page in the "placeholder" div.

Comment: thanks your answer works but how can i get the value of input text field when i want to dynamically generate forms with input fields and submit buttons with same name

Comment: that followup question seems to open a can of worms with not enough information to answer it.  You'd have to be more specific.

Comment: and how to know which submit button is pressed of which form and get that particular input field value

Comment: i can make 10 forms with 1 submit button and 1 input field with for loop and all those has same name and id and when i clicked on submit button i did not get the value of there input field how to to this is such a case without refreshing the page

Comment: I presume if you say dynamid you mean PHP .. so you can use a counter in a loop and increment like: (for $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) { <build your for here and use the $i in the names, etc>} .. then you can have as many forms as you want with different names.

Comment: i do all this as you say now how i get the value input field on pressing submit button without refreshing the page

Comment: please find this solution i will we very helpfull to me

Comment: yes i do all that now on myscreen there are 10 buttons now i want that when i click a button i can give the input value of that form this is my main problem

Comment: I added one line to your javascript that might give you a guideline to figure it out .. though the syntax may need some tweaking...

Comment: i use your code but no solution comes please suggest me some more examples

Comment: I have tried to give you a comprehensive best guess solution off the top of my head. I don't have a method to test my answers currently but it appears that you only need to search for a way to locate the current tValue for the first text element in each form. I will have to ask you to rely on research and persistence to resolve this.  I wish you best efforts in your endeavor.

Comment: please check indiamart.com and and click on send enquiry button i want that kind of company name on my modal box